# Getting error System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, Use one of these records?: []

Tags: salesforce1-app

```
public class salesforceOSearchlanguage {
    public static void sosl(){
        // Add account and related contact
        Account acct = new Account(
        Name='SFDC ComputingTest',
        Phone='(415)555-1212',
        NumberOfEmployees=50,
        BillingCity='San Francisco');
        insert acct;
        // Once the account is inserted, the sObject will be 
        // populated with an ID.
        // Get this ID.
        ID acctID = acct.ID;
        // Add a contact to this account.
        Contact con = new Contact(
               FirstName='CarolTest',
                LastName='Ruiz',
                Phone='(415)555-1212',
                Department='Wingo',
                AccountId=acctID);
        //insert con;
        // Add account with no contact
        Account acct2 = new Account(
            Name='The SFDC Query ManTest',
            Phone='(310)555-1213',
            NumberOfEmployees=50,
            BillingCity='Los Angeles',
            Description='Expert in wing technologies.');
//insert acct2;
      }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Duplicate rules are probably enabled and when it finds that there is a duplicate then it gives out this message

Answer (score 1):

This is coming because you have a duplicate rule present in your org which basically does not allow the creation of duplicate records.

To resolve this, first identify the duplicate rule that is causing the issue:

1. In Salesforce Setup, navigate to your Duplicate Rules.
2. Look for Rules that are affecting Leads, or Contacts.  They may be named something
   along the lines of: "Standard Rule for Leads with Duplicate Contacts", or "Standard
   Rule for Contacts with Duplicate Leads"
3. Click the title to open it up
4. Note that the Alert Text matches what you saw in the error message.  For example, "Use
   one of these records?"
5. Note that the "Alert" option is likely selected.

If you see that there is a Duplicate Rule such as described above, and the Alert checkbox is checked, then this is likely your issue.

You have three options to resolve this:

1. Deactivate the duplicate rule, or
2. Uncheck the Alert checkbox, or
3. Create a "condition" that will exempt